# fckeditor fileupload freeze, with autosave

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, fckeditor

i work with asp.net and use the fckeditor. i got autosave with ajax updatepanel on my page and when i use the fckeditor fileupload it freeze, i cant do nuthing it stays open and i cant close it. i dont know why?

i was thinking maby do a javascript that could detect if it was open then not run the autosave at that moment, you think that is a good solution? and how could i do that cause i am not that good at javascript..

apriciate all tips and help i can get

Answer (score 0):

There may be a file size upload limit on your server configuration.

Comment: nah. that is not my issue tho. but i think i am close to solv it. i am working on javascript that not gone run my autosave when the image upload is open.

maby i will return with questions about that.